# Typing to navigate to file in Windows Explorer when characters repeat

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When navigating to a file in Windows Explorer, I usually type out the name of the file, like "Myfile.doc". But if the file name has repeating characters, e.g. "Aardvark.doc" then when I type the 2nd "a", instead of sending me to files that begin with "aa", it gives me the 2nd file that begins with "a".

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep typing the letters in the filename until it is selected. For instance, when you type "AAR", it'll immediately jump to "Aardvark.doc", no matter how many files beginning with "A" are before or after "Aardvark".

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. What if I want to jump to a file named "zzzzzz", and there are thousands of files starts with "z"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Search field.  Navigate to the folder in Explorer, then The Search field will let you type AA and only files with AA would show.