# Typing to navigate to files with name starts with repeated character in windows file explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When navigating to a file in Windows Explorer, I usually type out the name of the file, like "Myfile.doc". But if the file name has repeating characters, e.g. "ZZZzzz.doc" then when I type the 2nd "z", instead of jumping to files that start with "zz", it gives me the 2nd file that starts with "z".

Is there any workaround or setting???

Note: I copied some description from [Similar Question](https://superuser.com/questions/871299/typing-to-navigate-to-file-in-windows-explorer-when-characters-repeat/871313#871313?newreg=40a19fef99c24e16afcd38bc6ed9c41f), and there is no correct answer there.

Comment: You have the same behavior with `Myfile.doc`, with the cursor jumping from `M` to `y` to `f` etc.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for reply. However, for files with name like "ABCDEF.doc", yes, it will jump to the correct position, but for name like "AAAAAAA.doc", it won't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround or setting for changing this behavior :
Explorer only looks at the first character of the name.

You need to look for an alternative file manager that has a better
selection algorithm.

My favorite is
[Altap Salamander](https://www.altap.cz/),
but there are many
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/altap-salamander/).

Comment: Thank you for answering the question and your recommendation. It is wired for Microsoft to design it this way though, it doesn't make sense. It seems that all the standard windows list controls behave this way, such as ListView control.

Comment: BTW, explorer doesn't only looks for the 1st character of the typed name,  this only happens when I type repeated characters. For un-repeated name, it searches for the whole name.

Comment: That's strange, because the graphical API used to display the file-names doesn't support it, and it doesn't happen on my Windows 10. Where do you type the characters?

Comment: Keyboard. This is how file explorer works on this: Type 'A', jump to the 1st file w/ name starts w/ 'A' and select it. Continue to type 'A' ('AA'), jump to the next file w/ name starts w/ 'A' and select it. Type 'AB', jump to the 1st file w/ name starts w/ 'AB' and select it. Type 'ABC...', jump to the 1st file w/ name starts w/ 'ABC...' and select it.

Comment: Which Windows version are you? In Windows 10, when I have files `a` and `ab`, typing `a` repeatedly shuttles between them, but typing `b` only beeps and doesn't move.

Comment: Edition: Windows 10 Enterprise, Version: 20H2, OS build: 19042.1110.

Comment: This should work the same as mine on 21H1. Do you have some Explorer add-on installed?

Comment: No add-on installed. My Windows Server 2016 Standard works the same way.

Comment: Very strange. It never worked for me this way across many computers. I can't explain why it works this way on your side. Last question: Does it also work when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Never tried but I guess it would be the same. The only issue here is w/ file name starts with repeated characters. But in Altap Salamander, this issue doesn't exist.

Comment: Explorer doesn't work the same as Salamander (my favorite file manager).